# conditional directive attribute without a value using ng-attr

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to achieve the following:

if $scope.loginData.use24hr is true, I want to invoke

```
<div class="timeline_text" ion-datetime-picker am-pm ng-model="datetimeValueTo.value" ng-change="dateChanged()">
```

if $scope.loginData.use24hr is false,  I want to invoke

```
<div class="timeline_text" ion-datetime-picker  ng-model="datetimeValueTo.value" ng-change="dateChanged()">
```

In other words, "am-pm" is the attribute that needs to conditionally go away.

`ion-datetime-picker` is a [3rd party directive](http://codepen.io/katemihalikova/pen/dYvjzP).

To achieve this I am doing:

```
<div class="timeline_text" ion-datetime-picker ng-attr-am-pm="{{!loginData.use24hr|| undefined}}"  ng-change="dateChanged()">
```

However, this always puts the am-pm attribute irrespective of the value of use24hr. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? Thanks

**Updates based on answers**

Edited to include **response to JC's answer**:

```
<ion-item>
   <div ion-datetime-picker title="From" ng-attr-am-pm="!!loginData.use24hr" ng-model="datetimeValueFrom.value">
    <b>VALUE:{{!loginData.use24hr}} From: </b>{{datetimeValueFrom.value | date: timeFormat}}
    </div>
</ion-item>
```

I've coerced boolean just to make sure but as you see irrespective of the value, the AM-PM directive always shows up

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute can take a value. To turn it off, use `am-pm={{!loginData.use24hr}}`

Note: Looks like it needs to be boolean `false` not just falsey. Any value other than boolean `false` will enable the am-pm behavior.

If you need to coerce your value to boolean, try this: `am-pm={{!!loginData.use24hr}}`

https://github.com/katemihalikova/ion-datetime-picker/blob/master/src/picker.js#L165

Comment: are you sure I need to add $scope- isn't $scope assumed?

Comment: Good catch. Yes. Sorry about that.

Comment: JC I'm sorry, but I'm seeing the same issue - please see updated post

Comment: It should be `am-pm` not `ng-attr-am-pm`

Comment: Ah great, so what eventually worked was ``am-pm={{!loginData.use24hr}} ``. Doing  ``am-pm="!loginData.use24hr"`` or ``am-pm="{{!loginData.use24hr}} "`` did not work. I'm curious why ng-attr didn't work though

Comment: What led you to try using ng-attr-? I've never even heard of it. edit: Just did some reading. Looks like it's for native attributes not directives. That'd be my guess.

Comment: Before you discovered that am-pm took a false value, I wanted to use ng-attr instead of repeating the div using ng-ifs. Would you like to edit your answer to include the string that worked? ``am-pm={{!loginData.use24hr}} `` - I can accept it.

Comment: Sure. Good advice when having trouble using a third party directive is to poke around in their source code to see how it uses the attributes.

Comment: That's weird, both `am-pm="{{!loginData.use24hr}}"` and `ng-attr-am-pm="{{!loginData.use24hr}}"` works fine for me with latest angular. What version are you using?